# issues with accessing URL with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have this web service which returns a JSON:

```
 http://54.246.99.134:8080/services-app/services/Users/GetConfigForMetroAndLang?metroAreaId=1&langId=39
```

When I access it using my browser, I get my JSON and all is working OK.
When I try to grab it with CURL or file_get_contents the page just keeps loading until :
**failed to open stream: Connection timed out**

Other URLS are working great when I try to get them from the server (any other address).

** edit **
Thanks for the comments

My code is very straight forward :)

```
$curl = curl_init('http://54.246.99.134:8080/services-app/services/Users/GetConfigForMetroAndLang?metroAreaId=1&langId=39'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/12.0');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result = curl_exec($curl); 
 print_r($result) ;
```

I now understand it works from a local host of one of my team mates...
so it is probably a server / firewall issue? any direction maybe?
** /edit **

Would really appreciate any idea.
Thanks!

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/n8bkfg). There must be some problem at your end.

Comment: Hi. Share your code please.

Comment: I've tried it both in browser and with php/file_get_contents. Both gave me a json response

Comment: Thanks, edited it. so the problem is either the code or server config... I tried another server (bluehost standard shared hosting with enabled curl) - same response :\

Comment: Why are you mixing $ch and $curl. Replace $ch with $curl in this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/12.0'); and this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: @Sabari - Thanks - I tried to add some custom headers to imitate a browser. Changed it, still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with your code, it is working fine for me.

Most probably the issues will be that your server cannot connect to an external resource, may be due to firewall restrictions.

Also `allow_url_fopen` needs to be On in your PHP settings for `file_get_contents` to work with URLs. You can check with this by printing out `phpinfo()` in any of your page.

Also don't use `file_get_contents` to get the contents or data because it  does not work well at all with getting remote files. It also does not deal with slow network connections or redirects, and does not return error codes. You should use `curl`, it is also faster than `file_get_contents`

Regarding your issue, I think it will be a firewall issue. Please check with your firewall settings.

Also, there is a mistake in your code. You are mixing $ch and $curl. It should be:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://54.246.99.134:8080/services-app/services/Users/GetConfigForMetroAndLang?metroAreaId=1&langId=39'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/12.0');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result = curl_exec($curl); 
 print_r($result) ;
```

You can use `curl_getinfo`  to get information regarding a specific transfer.

Comment: I guess you are right, must be some firewall or server config. Checked phpinfo - allow_url_fopen  is ON. Maybe a firewall issue :\... I'll try to contact the system admin for the server. Thanks

Comment: Having safe_mode=1 in your ini will override any allow_url_fopen settings you think you might be making...